# Jetty server on Vagrant Box hangs up at Started notification

Tags: windows, windows-7, jetty, vagrant, nfs

Using: Windows 7 Pro, Vagrant 2.0 with WINNFSD plugin and Jetty 6.1.11

When running Jetty through SSH on a Vagrant Box, my machine hangs up on the following lines:

```
[INFO] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

The problem is that I do not regain my ability to prompt. My Vagrantfile looks basically like this:

```rb
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "box_name"
  #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
  #config.vm.network "private_network", type: :dhcp

end
```

I can obviously SSH into the box, look through directories, etc. I just can't get past Jetty startup. Perhaps this is an NFS issue?

Comment: If I CTRL+C, the script exits successfully but also claims BUILD SUCCESS for the process.